# extract and resuse values from a structure

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I have a page called "shopping_cart_qry.cfm", that does a series of `SELECT` queries from various tables. It extracts data and populates a single structure called `shopping`. This structure contains around 50 parameters, like:

```
    shopping.company_id 
    shopping.brand_id 
    shopping.cost_Price
    shopping.expiry_dt
    shopping.user_id 
    shopping.item_name
    shopping.item_cost 
   ...
```

I only need 15 out of the 50 parameters (`shopping.item_name` , `shopping.item_cost`, etc) for a different task. So I am calling "shopping_cart_qry.cfm" as `<cfinclude>` in a new file named "item_info.cfm".

In this file when I do an `<cfdump>` of the structure, I see all 50 parameters, including the 15 parameters I need. But when I try to assign new names to the 15 parameters I need like this:

```
    <cfset itemName = "shopping.item_name">
    <cfset itemCost = "shopping.item_Cost">
    <cfset itemDt   = "shopping.item_Dt">
```

And then use `<cfdump>` to see I was able to do successfully, I am seeing the variable names (itemName, itemCost, etc..) but no values.

```
    <cfdump var="#shopping.item_name#">
    <cfdump var="#shopping.item_Cost#">
    <cfdump var="#shopping.item_Dt#">
```

Should I use `<script>`?

Answer (score 7):

You should remove the quotation marks, ex:

```
<cfset itemName = shopping.item_name>
```

See [Adobe docs on cfset](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_r-s_17.html).